# How to fix "return not in function" error that shown on firebug?

Tags: javascript

I try to prevent page reload when user click a link, so I wrote :

```
<a href="javascript: return false">bla</a>
```

Or

```
<a href="#">bla</a>
```

Seriously I don't like to use `#` because when user click on the link, the url on the address bar is added the symbol #, it make the url look ugly. So I prefer to use `javascript: return false` but firebug show error : "return not in function", may I know how to fix the error?

Comment: :-) not exactly. on clicking the link nothing will happen then why he need the href!!! i was inspired by sprynos answer :-)

Comment: lol. Very creative, but I need onclick attribute.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

See this discussion: [Which "href" value should I use for JavaScript links, "#" or "javascript:void(0)"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/134845/href-for-javascript-links-or-javascriptvoid0)

Do not use `href="#"`. If it has to be, either use `"javascript:;"` or `"javascript:void(0);"`

Answer (score 0):

Try using this instead:

```
<a href="javascript:;">bla</a>
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Look at this ([jsfiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/eDtyz/)):

```
<a href="http://www.google.com/" onclick="return false;">click me</a>
```

However, you should avoid using inline JavaScript. The JS in one place, separated from the code, has higher maintainability.